# chrome app scroll not working when there is even single fixed element

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, scroll, google-chrome-app

I have following chrome app. When I run it, main window displays but mouse scroll wheel does not work. When I open main.html in chrome, scrolling works fine. How to fix it?

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Scroll not working",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Scrolling in this chrome app is not working",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

background.js:

```
// Background script (displays main window)
'use strict';
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function () {
    chrome.app.window.create('main.html');
});
```

main.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="border: 1px solid red; position: fixed;">this fixed element will break the scroll wheel but only when it is run as chrome app, on normal page it will work ok</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>11</div>
    <div>12</div>
    <div>13</div>
    <div>14</div>
    <div>15</div>
    <div>16</div>
    <div>17</div>
    <div>18</div>
    <div>19</div>
    <div>20</div>
    <div>21</div>
    <div>22</div>
    <div>23</div>
    <div>24</div>
    <div>25</div>
    <div>26</div>
    <div>27</div>
    <div>28</div>
    <div>29</div>
    <div>30</div>
    <div>31</div>
    <div>32</div>
    <div>33</div>
    <div>34</div>
    <div>35</div>
    <div>36</div>
    <div>37</div>
    <div>38</div>
    <div>39</div>
    <div>40</div>
    <div>41</div>
    <div>42</div>
    <div>43</div>
    <div>44</div>
    <div>45</div>
    <div>46</div>
    <div>47</div>
    <div>48</div>
    <div>49</div>
    <div>50</div>
    <div>51</div>
    <div>52</div>
    <div>53</div>
    <div>54</div>
    <div>55</div>
    <div>56</div>
    <div>57</div>
    <div>58</div>
    <div>59</div>
    <div>60</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some default CSS applied for chrome packaged apps. Chrome packaged apps are most often intended to not scroll the main body content. Putting the following in your CSS should re-enable scrolling:

```
html, body {
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that worked, thanks. For similar reasons -webkit-user-select: none; is causing that mouse selection is disabled. Setting it to "initial" resolved that too.